# js fancybox and safari issue: cannot quit the modal dialog in safari!

Tags: jquery, safari, fancybox

functions fine in every other browser but safari.
selector is for a.class, in my case: $("a.nav")

When I do `<a class="nav" href=page.html><img src=icon.png/></a>`, it becomes not possible to close out of the modal dialog by clicking outside of the dialog or clicking the x icon.
what is my problem?

thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

hideOnContentClick = true?

Also a long shot but quoting the href and src attributes wouldn't hurt.

Answer (score 0):

honestly after a few hours I realized the src was an issue:

heres the offending line: "nothing can hurt me: the big star story.html"

```
<a class="nav" href="test.html" id="">
          <img src="b5.png" width="71" height="93">
</a>
<a class="nav" href="nothing can hurt me: the big star story.html" id="">
          <img src="b6.png" width="71" height="93">
</a>
```